# Skype SDK Conversation Control - Leaving a Conversation

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm using the Skype SDK Conversation Control to display chats and calls. Everything works fine except leaving a conversation. I tired to leave the conversation with `conversation.leave`. But all I get is an error that says that this function is disabled. Somewhere I also read that this function needs to be disabled when using Conversation Control. So I tried to leave the conversation with `conversation.chatService.stop`. But after executing this function nothing seems to happen and I am still able to chat with that person using the Conversation Control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is using `conversationsManager.conversations.remove(conversation)`.

https://ucwa.skype.com/reference/WebSDK/interfaces/_s4b_sdk_d_.jcafe.conversationsmanager.html#conversations